# How to calculate the perimeter from the intersection of the mesh and the cut line in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to calculate the perimeter of various irregular 3D objects, how can I do this in Unity 3D using C#?

My idea is:
Get a plane by inputting the coordinates of 3 points, then get the intersection of the plane and the object to be calculated, and then calculate the perimeter of the cumulative distance of these intersections.

But I have no idea to do this.

[image]

Comment: You said irregular objects, so this needs to work with any arbitrary shape and not just spheres? what about concave shapes?

Comment: I think I saw a [Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYbK_tjZ2OrIZFBvU6CCMiA) tutorial video on that once?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is one answer for every 3D object, if you want to find the perimeter for a particular shape you have to find the formula for that.
In case of a sphere:
[image]

c is position of the plane.
c0 is position of the sphere.
p is distance between c and c0.
r = sqrt(R2 - p2).
Then the perimeter of the intersection is: 2*r*pi.